# file program reading and writing python

Tags: python, file

```
endofprogram=False
try:
    filename=input('Enter file name: ')
    filename2=input('Enter file to write: ')
    infile=open(filename,'r')
    outfile=open(filename,'w')


    #IOError if file is not found
except IOError:
    print('End reading file--end of program')
    endofprogram=True

if(endofprogram==False):
    total=0
    alist=[]

    for line in infile:
        line=line.strip('\n')

        if(len(line)!=0)and line[0]!='#':
            name,grade=line.split('\t')
            total=total+float(grade)
            record=(name,float(grade))
            alist.append(record)
```

Here I am trying to write into a new file.

```
            outfile.write(name+'\n'+str(grade))

    average=total/len(alist)
    for item in alist:
        if item[1]<average:
            print(item)

    infile.close()
```

Hey guys. I was trying to understand file programs in python and just had a few questions.

2.Is my write into a new file statement correct because it gives me 'ZeroDivisionError after second line?

3.`name,grade=line.split('\t')`  work same as `name,grade=line.split()`  ?

Appreciate everyones effort . Thanks

Comment: Just making sure, in your except block in the code above, you are setting `enfofprogram` to be `True` not `endofprogram`. Spelling mistake in question or actual code?

Comment: i don't know what to say. it is supposed too be 'end of program'. I fixed that but 2 still is happening i.e. ZeroDivisionError

Comment: Secondly, to address your problem number 2, in some cases, you might have `len(alist)` to be 0 and therefore you get the `ZeroDivisionError`

Are you SURE that `len(alist)` can never be 0

Comment: Yes!. I tried running the program by just using reading statements and it works just fine. I put in the line 'if(len(line)!=0)and line[0]!='#':' to prevent what you just said.

Comment: How about you try running the program and before your `average=total/len(alist)` line put `print(alist)` and tell me what you got?

Comment: Hi I did what you said. the program stops after taking infile and outfile name.

Comment: In your `try` block, add `infile = infile.readlines()` after you open your two files

Comment: will that be necessary? the programs works without it just fine if i remove the write to file commands

Comment: when you open the file. you get a file object. therefore when you try to do line in infile it will let it happen without giving you an error. therefore, you must read the lines from your infile into a list

Comment: i wrote a similar program that worked fine without having to put in that code. FOR loop seemed to work fine too. I think adding that is just more confusion now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a few changes to your code and got it to work:

1) I open the first file, read it into a list and then close it

2) Also, you are opening both the files with the same name `filename`. It is a mistake. I think you meant to do `filename2` for the second `open`

To answer your question 3): Yes `string.split()` is the same thing as `string.split('\t')`

HERE is the working program:

```
endofprogram=False
try:
    filename=str(input('Enter file name: '))
    filename2=str(input('Enter file to write: '))
    infile_temp=open(filename,'r')
    infile=infilea.readlines()
    infile_temp.close()
    outfile=open(filename2,'w')

    #IOError if file is not found
except IOError:
    print('End reading file--end of program')
    endofprogram=True

if(endofprogram==False):
    total=0
    alist=[]

    for line in infile:
        line=line.strip('\n')

        if(len(line)!=0)and line[0]!='#':
            name,grade=line.split()
            total=total+float(grade)
            record=(name,float(grade))
            alist.append(record)

            outfile.write(name+" "+str(grade)+'\n')

    average=total/len(alist)
    for item in alist:
        if item[1]<average:
            print item
```

HOPE THAT HELPS